# How to grab the contents of a div and insert it into a hidden input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, laravel

I built a simple CMS in Laravel 4. I've decided to switch from my old editor to this [markdown editor](https://github.com/slhck/online-markdown-editor).

My old editor used a textbox and so all I had to do was submit the form and it was passed from the view to the controller and inserted into the database etc.

However, this new editor works by turning the markdown into html and that html is inserted within a div that looks like this:

```
<div id="preview" class="wmd-preview"></div>
```

I still want to use my old form to submit the contents of the div, so my question is this:

**Is there a way to insert the contents of my "preview" div into some sort of hidden input in my form?**

Alternatively, is there a better way to submit  the contents of my post?

Comment: i don't understand the question. for wmd editors, you have a textarea and a div which shows the output. whatever you write in the textarea, it shows in the preview. __You already__ have the content in the textarea. Why you need to copy them to another hidden input and submit?

Comment: Hi @itachi isn't that text area all just my markdown? It converts to html and that html is inserted inside the div not the textarea.

Comment: i didn't get what you are trying to say. look at stackoverflow's markdown editor. it has a textarea and below is the preview area. you just need to save the content of the text area and then when request is made, output it by parsing the content. there are numerous client or server side library there to help with the output.

Answer (score 1):

get the content of your `div` by its id

```
var a = document.getElementById('preview').innerHTML;
document.getElementById('hid').value = a   //create a hidden input give it an id hid
```

Comment: I'm thinking this will probably need to fire off every time I make a change to the text in my text editor. Is there a way to do that? (Sorry, I'm terrible at JS)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question about firing the function every time a key is pressed, I would use a jQuery event listener like .keyup().

http://api.jquery.com/keyup/